# jQuery does inline swipe event listener exist?

Tags: jquery, inline, swipe

i have an inline `onclick="myFunction('various parameters to pass to the function')"` on dynamically created elements that i would like to call on an hypothetical inline onswipe too.
I was wondering if the jQuery `.on('swipe' ..` can be used inline like that? doing `onswipe="myFunction()"` or how can i achieve that otherwise?
thanks

Comment: All built-in events have inline `onXXX` attributes.

Comment: But why not use event delegation for all your dynamic elements? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @Barmar is jquery's swipe built-in?

Comment: Apparently not. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Touch_events for a list of touch events that are currently supported by browsers.

Comment: @Barmar thanks seems like ontouchmove does the trick, now i have to understand how to customize it in terms of animation etc. i think you can post the above as an answer and i will mark as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent standard event is `touchmove`, so you can use `ontouchmove="..."`